# Erro de Impressão no ecrã

Tags: c

Boa tarde,

Estou a desenvolver uma aplicação em consola para um trabalho da universidade. O objetivo é criar uma aplicação de gestão do stock de uma farmácia usando linguagem C.

Criei a função de adicionar novos medicamentos (`AddNewDrug`) e de mostrar todos os elementos na lista (`ShowUpOrderedList`). No entanto, as informações não estão ser impressas corretamente.

Sei que o erro está provavelmente na função de adcionar uma vez que a função que imprime as informações imprime tudo o que é texto, só não imprime as variáveis.

Este é output na consola:

[image: Output do programa]

---

Este é o meu código:

*Função Adicionar*

```
void AddNewDrug(Drug **head, Drug **tail, int registryId, int drugId, char *designation, char *labName, int unitsInStock)
{
    // variables
    Drug *drugToAdd;

    // prepare drug to be added
    drugToAdd = (Drug*) malloc(sizeof(Drug));
    drugToAdd->registryId = registryId;
    drugToAdd->drugId = drugId;
    drugToAdd->unitsInStock = unitsInStock;
    strcpy(drugToAdd->designation, designation);
    strcpy(drugToAdd->labName, labName);

    // if the list is empty, add the drug on the first position (head and tail simulteanously)
    if(*head == NULL)
    {
        drugToAdd->next = NULL;
        drugToAdd->previous = NULL;
        *head = drugToAdd;
        *tail = drugToAdd;
    }
    else // if the list is not empty, compares the drug code to find if it is lower or higher and adds the drug
    {
        // local variables
        Drug *actual; // used to compare drug code and verify place of insertion

        // local variables initialization
        actual = head;

        // comparing drug code before adding drug. stops when finding a higher code or when finding a null element
        while(actual != NULL)
        {
            if(drugToAdd->drugId < actual->drugId)
            {
                actual = actual->next;
            }

            actual = actual->next;
        }

        // if the actual is the head, change the head
        if(actual == head)
        {
            drugToAdd->next = actual;
            drugToAdd->previous = NULL;
            actual->previous = drugToAdd;
            *head = drugToAdd;
        }
        else if(actual == NULL) // if the actual is after the tail, change the tail
        {
            drugToAdd->next = NULL;
            drugToAdd->previous = *tail;
            (*tail)->next = drugToAdd;
            *tail = drugToAdd;
        }
        else // actual is in the middle of the list
        {
        // adding the drug
        drugToAdd->next = actual;
        drugToAdd->previous = actual->previous;
        actual->previous->next = drugToAdd;
        actual->previous = drugToAdd;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Como, me parece, o problema está em sua função de impressão faltou você postar tal função.

Comment: Agradeço pelo comentário, mas o problema já foi resolvido. Encontrava-se sim na função de adicionar e era relativo a apontadores mal referenciados e condições de paragem erradas.